# How to determine "acute angle" between spatial curves?

Tags: calculus

[image]
I understand that the title is not quite accurate, so it's better to ask a question based on the graph. So, three spatial curves are given: blue (alpha), yellow (beta) and green (gamma). Here are their equations:

```
\[Alpha] = {1072 - 173.64999999999964` v - 1053.510000000002` v^2 - 
   4794.608388545948` v^3 + 10250.579098091992` v^4 - 
   4882.862709546044` v^5, -2579 + 367.7999999999993` v + 
   1085.800000000003` v^2 + 1474.5933742968045` v^3 - 
   4803.408260125245` v^4 + 2456.944885828447` v^5, 
  9.88383` + 643.53585` v - 560.0617000000002` v^2 - 
   604.8447774764995` v^3 + 817.3174429750306` v^4 - 
   192.31364549852992` v^5}
```

,

```
\[Beta] = {417.948` - 578.4099999999996` v - 
   243.95000000000118` v^2 + 393.08600000000206` v^3 - 
   296.9425000000008` v^4 + 121.26850000000013` v^5, -1997.27` + 
   259.14999999999964` v + 1303.1000000000022` v^2 - 2037.5` v^3 + 
   1427.8500000000058` v^4 - 475.4899999999998` v^5, 
  113.517` + 125.37` v + 476.27` v^2 - 2032.92` v^3 + 
   1893.0629999999996` v^4 - 652.1182` v^5}
```

,

```
\[Gamma] = {1072 - 173.64999999999964` v - 1053.510000000002` v^2 + 
   2103.8958575598153` v^3 - 3136.883524725092` v^4 + 
   1606.0956671652757` v^5, -2579 + 367.7999999999993` v + 
   1085.800000000003` v^2 - 794.1323873673391` v^3 - 
   449.44909006839225` v^4 + 371.7114774357324` v^5, 
  9.88383` + 643.53585` v - 560.0617000000002` v^2 - 
   1808.5353536247153` v^3 + 3135.9297882918345` v^4 - 
   1307.2354146671187` v^5}
```

. The coefficients are calculated in such a way that at a common point the derivatives of the first and second order are equal for beta and alpha, and for beta and gamma. The graph shows that in the case of beta/alpha, the curves seem to converge at an acute angle (I do not know how to express it more accurately), and in the case of beta/gamma there is no such acute angle. How can this be expressed mathematically? I mean, what property or parameter will allow you to say without seeing the graph that in the case of beta/alpha there is such an acute angle? And how is it mathematically correct to call this my "acute angle"? Thanks.

P.S.: I did all the calculations in Wolfram Mathematica.